# Actual size vs Virtual size

Tags: git

Am downloading a pacman git projects which is nearly 20gb.

But I have only 4gb available in actual size .whereas I have 200gb available in virtual.

Dynamically allocated storage.

Will I have any problem?..or must I increase the size of actual.?..if yes..then how?
Help me

Answer (score 3):

You most definitely will. Use this diagram:

(Your HDD) -> (Your Dynamic HDD) -> Pacman File

A dynamic Hard Disk Drive is a very useful device, which replaced the fixed virtual hard drive. The Dynamic HDD is a file that contains your VM's hard drive. However, it doesn't use all *n* gigabytes of space you assigned it. That *n* is a cap, the most  space it can take up. In your case, *n* = 200 GB. Your virtual machine considers this as a 200 GB drive plugged in to it. As space is used in the VM, the same amount of space is used in the file. For example, your VM shows you are using 190 GB of hard drive space. The Dynamic file will also be around 190 GB. The dynamic HDD will reach its cap with the addition of 10 GB.

There are 3 ways to increase the actual drive size (The Host Machine):

1. Go out any buy a new one.
2. Clean up unused programs, files, etc.
3. ***EMPTY THE RECYCLE BIN***. You would be surprised that sometimes 50+ gb just sits in the recycle bin.

Increasing your dynamic HDD space (as your problem is) is rather difficult if not impossible. The easiest way would be to create a new virtual drive of a large size and start using that as a dedicated drive for development, etc. Note that this adds a second drive, and does not increase the capacity of the first. To figure out how to do this, consult your software's manual.

You should always keep about 5% of your hard drive free for error logs, temp files, and similar short-lived data.